# Native Base FloatingLabel Focused Style

Tags: react-native, styles

Trying to re-style native-base floatinglabel on focus.

[image]

You see, on focus; my label comes so closer to top.
When I put "marginTop" It's ok, but on 'not-focused state' It comes bottom so much.

How can I change "focused label" style?

Here's my code:

```
<Item floatingLabel style={Style.inputStyles}>
                    <Label style={Style.labelStyle}>E-mail</Label>
                    <Input
                      textContentType={'emailAddress'}
                      value={formData.email}
                      onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                      name="email"
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                    />
                  </Item>
```

Here's my style file:

```
 inputStyles: {
        borderColor:'#eef1f7',
        borderLeftWidth:1,
        borderLeftColor:'#eef1f7',
        borderRightWidth:1,
        borderRightColor:'#eef1f7',
        borderTopWidth:1,
        borderTopColor:'#eef1f7',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        color:'#334864',
        borderRadius:8,
        marginBottom:10,
        paddingLeft:10,
        fontSize:15,
        fontWeight:"500",
        height:65,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        paddingLeft:10,
        color:'#a5b1bc',
        fontSize:14
      },
```

Comment: remove height and check how it shows the view

Comment: the problem continues as the same. only input is smaller.